# Bind web xml attributes in listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I m binding the web xml but its reading only first record

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<content>
  <content_row id="1" day="1" title="test" from="01:10" first_name="jitendra" last_name="shakyawar" about_keynote="test" image="1326091608.jpg" innhold="1" about_speaker="test" desc="" flattr_url=""/>
  <content_row id="4" day="1" title="test 4" from="04:20" first_name="" last_name="" about_keynote="" image="" innhold="2" about_speaker="" desc="Test 4" flattr_url=""/>
</content>
```

XAML:

```
<cc:TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,80,0,0">
                <cc:TabItem Name="tabDag1" Height="50" Width="80" Header="Dag 1"  Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1}" Foreground="Black" >
                <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                    <ListBox  Name="listDag1" Width="440" Background="Black">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"   Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,20,20,0">
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"  Text="{Binding From}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="28"/>
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Text="{Binding AboutSpeaker}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
            </cc:TabItem>
    </cc:TabControl>
```

C#

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("content")
           select new ContentItems
           {
               FirstName = (query.Element("content_row") == null) ? "" : (string)query.Element("content_row").Attribute("first_name").Value,
               LastName = (query.Element("content_row") == null) ? "" : (string)query.Element("content_row").Attribute("last_name").Value,
               From = (query.Element("content_row") == null) ? "" : (string)query.Element("content_row").Attribute("from").Value,
               AboutSpeaker = (query.Element("content_row") == null) ? "" : (string)query.Element("content_row").Attribute("about_speaker").Value
           };

listDag1.ItemsSource = data;
```

Comment: xdoc.Descendants("content_row") why don't you use this

Comment: if i use this then showing null exception error.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you're misunderstanding how to use Linq2xml. You shouldn't include the root element in the query. So your query should look somewhat like this:

```
var data =
        from query in xdoc.Descendants("content_row")
        select new ContentItems
        {
            FirstName = query.Element("content_row").Attribute("first_name").Value,
            LastName = query.Element("content_row").Attribute("last_name").Value,
            From = query.Element("content_row").Attribute("from").Value,
            AboutSpeaker = query.Element("content_row").Attribute("about_speaker").Value
        };
```

Of course, in the case that the attribute is missing, you'll have to check for it manually.

Comment: If you can't handle that, you should go read up on the very basics of C#. We can't help you, when you don't understand what we tell you.